# How can I group items in a ruby array based on characteristics of each element?

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

I have a letter array created by splitting any given word. I have a constant array of all five vowels, and I use that to classify each letter in the letter array as either a consonant or a vowel.

```
VOWELS = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

letters = "compared".split("")
   # => ["c", "o", "m", "p", "a", "r", "e", "d"] 

word_structure = letters.map { |letter| VOWELS.include?(letter) ? "v" : "c" }
   # => ["c", "v", "c", "c", "v", "c", "v", "c"]
```

I want to somehow achieve two things:

1. Group adjacent letters in the "letters" array that have the same "word_structure".
2. Take those groups and return each possible VCV combination as another array. V represents a grouping of all adjacent vowels, and C represents a grouping of all adjacent consonants.

.

```
 groups = ["c", "o", "mp", "a", "r", "e", "d"]

 vcv_groups = ["-co", "ompa", "are", "ed-"]
```

In this example, the first VCV group begins with a "-" because there is no first grouping of vowels. The next two groupings fit the pattern fully, and the last has another "-" because there was no final vowel to complete the pattern.

I've experimented with Enumerable#chunk, Enumerable#partition and Enumerable#slice_before, but they're all just confusing to me. If somebody understands a simple way to achieve this, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: This looks like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a regex (followed by a messy bit to insert hyphens as required):

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'

R = /
    (?=                # begin positive look-ahead
      (                # begin capture group 1
        (?:            # begin a non-capture group   
          [#{VOWELS}]+ # match one or more vowels
          |            # or
          \A           # match the beginning of the string
        )              # end non-capture group
        [^#{VOWELS}]+  # match one or more consonants
        (?:            # begin a non-capture group
          [#{VOWELS}]+ # match one or more vowels
          |            # or
          \z           # match end of string
        )              # end non-capture group
      )                # end capture group 1
    )                  # end positive lookahead
    /x                 # extended mode

 def extract(str)
   arr = str.scan(R).flatten
   arr[0].insert(0, '-') unless VOWELS.include?(arr[0][0])
   arr[-1] << '-' unless VOWELS.include?(arr[-1][-1])
   arr
 end

 extract 'compare'    #=> ["-co", "ompa", "are"] 
 extract 'compared'   #=> ["-co", "ompa", "are", "ed-"] 
 extract 'avacados'   #=> ["ava", "aca", "ado", "os-"] 
 extract 'zzz'        #=> ["-zzz-"] 
 extract 'compaaared' #=> ["-co", "ompaaa", "aaare", "aare", "are", "ed-"]
```

Comment: How can I update it so that it would catch the last group if the word was changed to "compared"? The last group there should be "ed-"

Comment: I'm sorry for not just using "compared" as my example word. It could have been clearer.

Comment: I changed it to deal with a missing vowel at the end as well.

Comment: I've accepted it as the best answer. Thanks so much @caryswoveland. I just have to figure out how to get that dash at the beginning of leading groups and the dash at the end of trailing groups.

Comment: I did another edit to insert hyphens at the beginning and end, as required.

Comment: "school" => ["-schoo", "ool", "ol-"]

Comment: How can I change/combine ["ool", "ol-"] to ["ool-"] ?

Comment: I figured out how to eliminate any extracted group that is a substring of the string beside it. It's not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
"compare"
.split(/([aeiou]+)/).unshift("-").each_cons(3)
.each_slice(2).map{|(v1, c, v2), _| v2 ||= "-"; [v1, c, v2].join}
```

Comment: This is awesome. But the same reason that some groups are -CV in format would cause others to be VC- in format (if a word ends on a consonant). Can you explain this answer so that I can try to modify it to also use the VC- format constraint?

Comment: @sawa it's breaking because of 'v2 = "-"' Is there an alternative way to write that? I don't understand it enough to edit it myself